# How can I find a max value of a selected region in a fit?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find a max value of a curve fitted plot for a certain region in this plot. I have a 4th order fit, and when i use max(x), the ans for this  is an extrapolated value, while I am actually looking fot the max value of the 'bump' in my data.
So question, how do I select the max for only a certain region in the data while using a cfit? Or how do I exclude a part of the fit?

```
LF = pol4Fit(L,F);
Coefs= coeffvalues(LF);
```

This code does only give the optimum (the max value) of the real points:

```
L_opt = feval(LF,L);
[F_opt,Num_Length]= max (L_opt);
Opt_Length= L(Num_Length);
```

So now I was trying something like: `y=max(LF(F))`, but this is not specific to select a region.

Comment: Can you please edit the code, that you have so far?

Comment: LF = pol4Fit(L,F)
Coefs= coeffvalues(LF);

This code does only give the optimum (the max value) of the real points:

L_opt = feval(LF,L);  % 
[F_opt,Num_Length]= max (L_opt);      
Opt_Length= L(Num_Length);

So now I was trying something like:
for i = F(1:end)
y=LF(max(F))
end

Which does not work.

Comment: Please edit your whole code into the question.

Comment: @Max, Sorry I pressed enter to soon. Thanx for reading and answering!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to only evaluate the region you are interested in.
For instance, let's say the specific region is a vector named `S`.
You can simply rewrite your code like below:

`L_opt = feval(LF,S);`

Use the specific domain region `S` instead of the whole domain `L` and it only evaluates the region you are concerned with. Then using `max` function should work properly for you.